# Get column from same row power query

Tags: excel, api, powerquery, m

I have a power query that is making an api request with some value in a column as a parameter. Normally in Excel, you would say something like `=A1` then drown the cell down and get a response from A2, A3, etc. How do you do this with powerquery? Here is my function so far but it only takes the first result of the column.

`Json.Document(Web.Contents("API?symbol=" & Source{0}[Column1] ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `Source{0}[Column1]` says to take the first row of `Column1` of the table `Source` (which I'm assuming is the name of the first step in the query).

Instead of referencing a row and column of an entire table, you can probably just use `[Column1]`, which should refer to the value in the current row. Try this as the formula for a new custom column instead:

```
Json.Document(Web.Contents("API?symbol=" & [Column1] ))
```